# Tweepy to access Twitter streaming API using python 3.4

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I'm unable to use tweepy to access Twitter streaming API using the following example code using python 3.4. This code was running using python 2.4. What is wrong ?

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener


ckey = ''
csecret = ''
atoken = ''
asecret = ''

class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print (data)
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print (status)

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["obama"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is exactly correct.

But on Windows Vista/7, with UAC, administrator accounts run programs in unprivileged mode by default.
Or it might be possible that you are trying to run on a port the current user account does not have permission to bind to. Run the following code to detect your script has admin access or not.

```
import ctypes
print ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
```

If it prints 1 then its ok. If 0 then your script doesn't have admin access.